# Rebase-only merge requests in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

There are two protected branches in the project I`m working on: `master` and `perf`. The latter is supposed to be kept in sync with the former but has several extra commits on top.

The project is hosted on an internal GitLab.

I`ve been approved a commit to `master` and now am struggling to create a «special» MR that would rebase `perf` onto the new `master`.

How do I do that, considering that both branches are protected?

Comment: Why do you need would rebase merge on `perf`? What is the issue with normal `merge` request?

Comment: @PrathapReddy Because of the repo policy I guess.

Comment: So you are question is, The `master` went ahead accidentally because of your PR `merge`, How to make it in sync with `Pref` since it's behind? Correct me If I interpreted wrongly here.

Comment: @PrathapReddy First, not accidentally but deliberately. Second, due to the repo policy our MRs do not produce merge commits.

Comment: Having protected branches is basically _forbidding_ rebases like what you attempt of `perf` onto `master`. Just saying....

Comment: @eftshift0 Couldn`t find that in [the definition of a protected branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html) in the official GitLab documentation. Force pushes prohibited? Yes. Rebasing prohibited? No.

Comment: rebases _imply_ **force pushing**.

Comment: @eftshift0 Exactly why I need this done on the server, to eliminate a force push.

Comment: Not following. Your 2 last paragraphs in the question are mutually exclusive. Either the branches are protected and you _can't_ rebase the branches because they will be rejected (because you can't force push).... or you _unprotect_ them and then you can rebase and force-push. Can't see how _doing a rebase on the server_ (whatever that means) will allow you to avoid a force-push if rebases rewrite the history of a branch... which is what is discouraged by a protected branch in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218845/discussion-between-hidefromkgb-and-eftshift0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I happened to be looking for was to **merge** `master` into `perf`, not to **rebase** `perf` onto the new `master`.

Problem solved.